# Netbeans C/C++ JavaDoc code-completion

Tags: c++, c, netbeans, javadoc, code-completion

I am developing C++ in NetBeans 6.7.1. When I press CTRL + space for autocomplete there is shown only method's signature. I am using JavaDoc for commenting my code but NetBeans doesn't show it. I have installed Doxygen plugin but it is only for generating complete documentation.

Is there any way how to force the IDE to show signature and JavaDoc for C++ please?

I think that it should not be a problem because this functionality is currently implemented for Java.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes. JavaDoc is type of comments, C++ has no own type of comments and there are technologies like Doxygen which supports JavaDoc with C++. So why not. And NetBeans supports javadoc because of Java so I see no reason why it should be impossible for C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I asked on NetBeans forum this [question](http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=60503#60503) ( using friend's account because I don't have my own ) and there is the conclusion: It is impossible and it is in requests.